# mux Router type for returned anonymous function

Tags: go, mux

I have this:

```
type RegisterHandler struct{}

func (h RegisterHandler) Mount(router *mux.Router, v interface{}) {
    router.HandleFunc("/register", h.MakeRegisterNewUser(v))
}

func (h RegisterHandler) MakeRegisterNewUser(v interface{}) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

the return type of the returned func is `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)`, my question is - there is already a type for that return type, surely. `mux.Router.Handler`? or something like that? Anyone know what the existing type is for that?

Comment: See [http.HandlerFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc).

Comment: `http.HandleFunc is not a type`, but maybe I should actually read your link and find out ..

Comment: `http.HandlerFunc`  not `http.HandleFunc`.

Comment: oh fuk me sideways, thx, didn't see the r